# DNS settings resolve to two different SPF records

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53, spf

I've added a TXT record with SPF information in order to verify my domain with Mandrill. I've also added a TXT record for the DKIM settings.

The problem is that when Mandrill attempts to verify these records, it resolves to an SPF record that I've not setup in my DNS settings, thus its missing the settings that Mandrill requires.

I've used several DNS check tools and most of them resolve to the TXT records that I've setup, but some of them resolve to this SPF record:

> v=spf1 a mx ptr include:secureserver.net ~all

1) Is there any way to track down the source of this record? How does it resolve to this SPF that I've not setup anywhere on my DNS settings?

2) How come different tools/test servers resolve to different SPF records? If Mandrill could resolve to the one that I've setup, I could verify my domain, but now it resolves to the other. Is there any way to get past this?

I should also mention that:

- I'm using Amazon's Hosted Zone in Route53 to manage my DNS settings
- I've added records to connect Google Suite with this domain

Thanks!

Comment: What is the domain?

Comment: The domain is thefutureofjewelry.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Route 53 is authoritative for your domain, but your Route 53 zone appears to have had its default `NS` records deleted and replaced with `ns15.domaincontrol.com` and `ns16.domaincontrol.com`.

Those servers, in turn, are the source of the wrong `TXT` record.  It's not really correct for inaccurate NS records to be treated as an apex re-delegation, but that appears to be what's happening, and explains inconsistent answers.

The `NS` records that Route 53 automatically populated when you create a hosted zone should not be edited.  You need to put them back as they originally were.

In the list of hosted zones in Route 53, click the blank area inside the correct *row* of your hosted zone (not the domain name itself -- you want to highlight it without opening it) and the correct 4 NS values should appear on the right side of the screen.  Use those values to correct the NS record inside the hosted zone.

Comment: Beat me to it...

Comment: You were right, I've never questioned this record, and maybe I should have! Thank you both for your help :)